# An alternative solution for sendmail problem

Tags: sendmail

I use sendmail on solaris

I want a secure configuration so i use TLS 1.2 and RunAsUser
configured with user smmsp.

Permission are correct and tls works fine.

But when i run email give me this error

```
only super-user can use -l option
```

I "solved" using

`chmod u+s mail.local`

,but honestly i dislike this solution.

Someone know a better solution for this problem?

Comment: `smmsp` is usually for the MSP (configured by `submit.cf`). Did you change the user in `sendmail.cf` as well?

Comment: sure, RunAsUser configured with user smmsp.I have to use another user?

Comment: Without root you'll need to do the setuid bit on the local mailer, or perhaps use a different local mailer protocol (LMTP?) to avoid that suid bit problem.